# No puedo realizar este problema de poo

Tags: python, poo

me estoy preparando para un parcial de poo y hay un ejercicio que no me sale:
Es ya que tengo problemas con el tema de tuplas
el ejercicio es el siguiente:

Debemos representar un personaje de un videojuego. El personaje se mueve en un mundo de dos dimensiones (x, y) y cuando comienza el juego se encuentra ubicado en la posición (0,0) y su nivel de energía están en 10 (ese valor se inicializa siempre con 10).

El personaje tiene estos métodos asociados:

- Constructor: el método constructor -además de definir el estadio inicial- deberá recibir como parámetro el nombre del personaje (string)
- Avanzar(lista_movimientos): lista_movimientos es una lista de tuplas, donde cada tupla tiene el siguiente formato (dirección, casilleros). Dirección es un string y puede ser “norte”, “sur”, “este”, “oeste”, mientras que casilleros indica la cantidad de casilleros a moverse (será un número  entero). Por ejemplo, si el personaje ha sido recién creado (está en el origen) entonces invocar a este método Avanzar( [ (“norte”, 1), (“este”, 2) ] ) dejaría a nuestro personaje en la posición (2, 1). Tener en cuenta que cada vez que se mueve un casillero se consume una unidad de energía (en el ejemplo anterior, el primer movimiento consumió 1 y el segundo 2, por lo tanto como arrancó en 10, luego de invocar Avanzar el nivel de energía estará en 7). Un detalle: solo se realiza un movimiento si existe energía disponible para ir en esa dirección; si en el ejemplo la lista de movimientos es [ (“norte”, 9), (“este”, 2)], avanzaría hasta (0, 9), tendría 1 unidad de energía remanente y con eso no le alcanza para el segundo movimiento, por lo tanto se quedará en ese último lugar y no seguirá con el resto de los movimientos, es decir, hará todos los movimientos posibles. Cuando puede hacer todos los movimientos, los hace y listo; cuando no puede seguir con los movimientos, se queda en el último posible y debe imprimir un cartel que diga “No he podido completar el avance. Me he detenido en la posición (x, y)” donde x e y es la posición real donde quedó.
- CargarEnergia(unidades): aumenta (es decir agrega) la energía indicada al personaje
- Ubicación: devuelve una tupla con las coordenadas (x,y) del personaje
- Distancia(OtroPersonaje): devuelve la distancia que existe entre el personaje del objeto y OtroPersonaje que se pasa como parámetro
- El  getter del nivel de energía del personaje
- Un método que cuando se haga print(personaje) imprima información del personaje: nombre, ubicación, energía.
  hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
class Personaje:

      def __init__(self,nombre):
        self.posicion=(0,0)
        self.energia=10
        self.nombre=nombre
      
    
      def __str__(self):
        return f"personaje: \n\tNombre: {self.nombre}"
    
      def Avanzar(self,listamovimientos):
        posicion=listamovimientos
        if listamovimientos>=self.energia:
          self.energia=listamovimientos-self.energia
        else:
          self.energia=self.energia-listamovimientos
        print("el personaje se encuentra ubicado en la posicion",posicion,"y su nivel de energia es de ",self.energia)
      
      def ubicacion(self):
        ubicacion=self.posicion
        print(" el personaje se encuentra ubicado en la posicion",ubicacion)
        
        
    
    
      def cargarenergia(self,unidades):
        unidades=unidades+self.energia
        print("su energía es de",unidades)
        return unidades
    
    
    
      
      def distancia(self,otro):
        distancia=otro-self.posicion
        print("la distancia entre el otro personaje es",distancia)
    
    
      def getenergia(self):
        return self.energia
        
    
    
        
        
        
    
    
    personaje1=Personaje("Jose")
    personaje1.Avanzar([("norte", 4),("este", 2),("sur", 1)])
    personaje1.ubicacion()
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: ahí puse mi código, no sé como si el método avanzar recibe una lista de tuplas, restarle los valores de la energía para que así se cuánta energía me queda, porque por ejemplo si yo le doy avanzar ([("norte", 4),("este", 2),("sur", 1)]) mi energía tendría que quedar en 2 ya que por cada casilla consume un nivel de energía, pero como le resto lo que pongo en avanzar a mi energía inicial que es 10

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon en la pregunta lo que has comentado, además de modificar el título: nadie encontrará tu pregunta si se titula "No puedo realizar este problema de poo". La pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

El código de avanzar debería ser:

```
def Avanzar(self,listamovimientos):
    """Avanzar con una lista de movimientos, 
   listamovimientos es un array que contiene tuplas del tipo (str,int)
   donde str es la dirección asociada al paso y int la cantidad de pasos.
   (ver enunciado). """

    for direccion,distancia in listamovimientos: #recorro cada movimiento
    if distancia > self.energia: #me fijo si tengo energía para moverme
        #esto es, la energía no es necesaria
        print("No se puede seguir avanzando, no hay energía")
        break
    else: #si tengo energía 
        self.energia -= distancia #resto la energía
        x,y = self.posicion #separo la posición en x,y
        if direccion=='norte': #checkeo la direccion con las keywords de direcciones
            y+= distancia
        if direccion=='sur':
            y-= distancia
        if direccion=='este':
            x+= distancia
        if direccion=='oeste':
           x-= distancia
        self.posicion =(x,y) #guardo la nueva posición
```

Como dice el enunciado, primero, `listamovimientos` es una lista con tuplas de la forma `(str,int)` donde el primer valor indica la dirección y el segundo cuantos pasos. Luego checkear que para ese "paso" alcance la energia, moverse y restar la energía. Por lo tanto, lo que hay que hacer es

1- Recorrer cada tupla (esto lo hace el for).
2- Checkear si la energía es suficiente (`if distancia>energia`)
3- Si la energía alcanza hay que traducir la dirección en un eje de la tupla (x,y), eso lo hace el conjunto de if adicionales.

Como por definición del OP, la posición es una tupla, es necesario desarmarla para actualizar los valores por separado y volver a armarla (esto es el `(x,y)=...` y el `self.posicion =...` al que envuelven al conjunto de if de direcciones)

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).